# Visio 2010 Professional website map - can't find the template

Tags: website, microsoft-visio

According to the edition [comparison](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/visio-edition-comparison-FX101838162.aspx), Visio 2010 Professional has the following feature "**Web site mapping and documentation** including auto-generation of Web site maps".  However, I can't find these templates or the functionality to perform this.  I installed all of the features, is there something I missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in "Software and Database" under "Template Categories". You'll be prompted for a URL when you create the document.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Comment: I think that's the problem.  All I have is Basic Network Diagram.  Are templates from Visio 2007 compatible?

Comment: It took me a minute to find it too. You need to select the "Software and Database" category. (See 1st screenshot. I've clarified.) I don't know if Visio 2007 templates are compatible but I'd expect them to be, or for there to be a conversion process.